# Using OCR to recognize icons

Tags: ocr, image-recognition

Can OCR projects be trained to recognize common icons? (i.e - twitter, facebook, instagram, etc.)

Edit: More descriptive information about the problem - I have a set of small png images, that can be anything at all, but I would like to recognize cases in which they match a specific pattern (as arrows, specific social icons, etc.)

If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can. But do you really need it? From the information in your question, I can't tell.

Things not covered in your question that might affect my answer:

- the size of the input images;
- how much the images may differ from the icons you are trying to detect;
- how many different icons you want to learn;
- do you want to detect the icon in a plain image that can only contain the icon or in the wild?

There might be more things to take into consideration.

If all you want is to take a PNG image and tell whether this is one of your known icons, I wouldn't even bother with any OCR. A simple 1-nearest neighbors approach should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To answer your questions:
1. The size of the images will be relatively small, typically no more than 50x50 
2. It may differ greatly, and be something else entirely.
3. I am looking currently at no more than 20 popular patterns but it may become bigger
4. The image will only contain the icon, isolated and not it the wild